# Xamarin Android activity duplicated in AndroidManifest error

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I'm working on a app in Xamarin Android and got stuck on this error, after changing target sdk/Android version from Android 9 to Android 10:
[image: Error]

my AndroidManifest (**in Visual Studio!**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="0.7.1" package="com.INCREDIBLE.Video2mp3" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="3">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@drawable/micon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/micon">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="Download als mp3">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

But **in the Solution folder** the Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="0.7.1" package="com.INCREDIBLE.Video2mp3" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="3">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@drawable/micon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/micon" android:name="android.app.Application">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:label="Download als mp3">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/micon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.INCREDIBLE.Video2mp3.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.INCREDIBLE.Video2mp3.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

The App should only have one Activity (MainActivity). If deleting the 'duplicated' `<activity ... />`   (in the file directly) I get no error massage, but the build fails anyways. Before the version changed from 9 to 10, it worked as expacted. Now (even when I change the target Version back to 9) I get stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xamarin, you don't need to explicitly register Activities in the Manifest. You can delete all activity code from the manifest and use Attributes in the source file like so:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.SEND" }, Label = "Download als mp3", Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" }, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
public class MainActivity: Activity
{
```

Note: You may be doing both due to which a second entry for the activity maybe gets added to the manifest when you build the project

Comment: That seems to work, but the app crashes while starting now (Before OnCreate is called).

Comment: I get no error, but it's an other topic (Looks like something is wrong with storage permissions - crashes after asking for permission, but I never requested them)