# Xamarin Android Manifest Generates Duplicated Lines

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-manifest

Whenever I build the project, it creates the manifest file again and writes it twice on the same lines.
This causes an error during build.
Every time I want to run it, I have to manually delete it and build it like that.
I tried doing clean and then rebuilding.
I deleted the obj and bin folders and tried again I get all kinds of the same error.
Any ideas?

This is AndroidManifest.xml in App.obj/App.Android/Obj/Debug/90/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.companyname.takikuyumculuk" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <application android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="takikuyumculuk.Android">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.companyname.takikuyumculuk" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <activity android:name="crc64f5fdbb1c1efd8769.MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="TakÄ±Kuyumculuk" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="crc64f5fdbb1c1efd8769.MyFirebaseIIDService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="crc64f5fdbb1c1efd8769.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.takikuyumculuk.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" />
    <!-- suppress ExportedReceiver -->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.companyname.takikuyumculuk" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.takikuyumculuk.firebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" />
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" android:exported="false">
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--
             FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--
             FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <service android:name="crc64a98abb514ffad9f1.KeepAliveService" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.companyname.takikuyumculuk.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.companyname.takikuyumculuk.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
  </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the error while I building the project.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Android activity duplicated in AndroidManifest error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648264/xamarin-android-activity-duplicated-in-androidmanifest-error)

Comment: There’s no problem on activity.. receiver tags and monoandroidruntime row duplicates when project builded.

Comment: Okay. Can you add your original Manifest file to the question

Comment: This is the original manifest file above, and i get error when i build generates duplicated lines when i delete these manually works after i get error when i built it

Comment: What about the one in Properties. `Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: How can i send the xml code there are no enough character to write it.Which tags should i use while using code in comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221020/discussion-between-onur-n-and-siddharth-sharma).

Comment: @Onurİn Any update? Could you share your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Hey @WendyZang-MSFT ,
I solved the problem by removing duplicated lines from AndroidManifest.xml which exists in Android.Properties. After I Rebuild it and problem is solved :) Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing duplicated lines from AndroidManifest.xml which exists in Android.Properties. After I Rebuild it and problem is solved :)